# Javascript Anonymous Function Issue

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have this basic anonymous function:

```
var config = [];

var scope = {
    getSegments:function(){
        console.log('List of Segments')
    }
}


var run = (function (config, scope) {

    scope.getSegments();

    return true

})(config,scope);
```

When I type `run` into the console, I get `true` returned, however I dont see the console log that I have in the `scope` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes it does print the console.log

Comment: Are you sure? I just pasted your code on jsbin and it's logging.

Comment: Same here.. https://jsfiddle.net/n82o75gp/

Comment: Do you expect the anonymous function to execute every time you access the value of `run`? (It does not; it runs exactly once.) Is that what you *want* to do? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to proof it, the function works!

```js
var config = [],
    scope = {
        getSegments: function() {
            document.write('List of Segments');
        }
    },
    run = (function (config, scope) {
        scope.getSegments();
        return true;
    })(config, scope);
```

Comment: Doh! It ran at load, not when I typed run. I guess as it should of. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run contains the results of a self executing function, so it will print the log when executed and afterwards it will have the value true.